# How do I resolve "Unable to resolve attribute [organizationType.id] against path" exception?

Tags: hibernate, jpa, entitymanager, hibernate-criteria

I'm using Spring 3.1.1.RELEASE, Hibernate 4.1.0.Final, JUnit 4.8, and JPA 2.0 (hibernate-jpa-2.0-api).  I'm trying to write a query and search based on fields of member fields.  What I mean is I have this entity …

```
@GenericGenerator(name = "uuid-strategy", strategy = "uuid.hex")
@Entity
@Table(name = "cb_organization", uniqueConstraints = {@UniqueConstraint(columnNames={"organization_id"})})
public class Organization implements Serializable
{

    @Id
    @NotNull
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "uuid-strategy")
    @Column(name = "id")
    /* the database id of the Organization */
    private String id;

    @ManyToOne 
    @JoinColumn(name = "state_id", nullable = true, updatable = false)
    /* the State for the organization */
    private State state;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "country_id", nullable = false, updatable = false)
    /* The country the Organization is in */
    private Country country;

    @ManyToOne(optional = false) 
    @JoinColumn(name = "organization_type_id", nullable = false, updatable = false)
    /* The type of the Organization */
    private OrganizationType organizationType;
```

Notice the members "organizationType," "state," and "country," which are all objects.  I wish to build a query based on their id fields.  This code

```
@Override
public List<Organization> findByOrgTypesCountryAndState(Set<String> organizationTypes,
                                                        String countryId,
                                                        String stateId)
{
    CriteriaBuilder builder = entityManager.getCriteriaBuilder();
    CriteriaQuery<Organization> criteria = builder.createQuery(Organization.class);
    Root<Organization> org = criteria.from(Organization.class);
    criteria.select(org).where(builder.and(org.get("organizationType.id").in(organizationTypes),
                                            builder.equal(org.get("state.id"), stateId),
                                            builder.equal(org.get("country.id"), countryId)));
    return entityManager.createQuery(criteria).getResultList();
}
```

is throwing the exception below.  How do I heal the pain?

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unable to resolve attribute [organizationType.id] against path
    at org.hibernate.ejb.criteria.path.AbstractPathImpl.unknownAttribute(AbstractPathImpl.java:116)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.criteria.path.AbstractPathImpl.locateAttribute(AbstractPathImpl.java:221)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.criteria.path.AbstractPathImpl.get(AbstractPathImpl.java:192)
    at org.mainco.subco.organization.repo.OrganizationDaoImpl.findByOrgTypesCountryAndState(OrganizationDaoImpl.java:248)
    at org.mainco.subco.organization.repo.OrganizationDaoTest.testFindByOrgTypesCountryAndState(OrganizationDaoTest.java:55)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:44)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:15)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:41)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:20)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.java:74)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.java:83)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.SpringRepeat.evaluate(SpringRepeat.java:72)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:231)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:49)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:193)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:52)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:191)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:42)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:184)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:236)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:174)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:50)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:467)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:683)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:390)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:197)
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

JPA Criteria building does not define support for path expressions.  The correct Criteria would be:

```
CriteriaBuilder builder = entityManager.getCriteriaBuilder();
CriteriaQuery<Organization> criteria = builder.createQuery(Organization.class);
Root<Organization> org = criteria.from(Organization.class);
criteria.select(org);
criteria.where(
    builder.and(
        org.get( "organizationType" ).get( "id" ).in( organizationTypes ),
        builder.equal( org.get( "state" ).get( "id" ), stateId ),
        builder.equal( org.get( "country" ).get( "id" ), countryId )
    )
);
```