# Spring Boot / JPA: Why would war conversion break functionality and/or JPA searches?

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-boot, jpa, broadleaf-commerce

I am running a application based on the Community version of Broadleaf Commerce demo site (hot sauce).

To experiment with CI and deployment options, we have converted the stock spring boot packaging (jar) to war following the [broadleaf](https://www.broadleafcommerce.com/docs/core/current/broadleaf-concepts/key-aspects-and-configuration/app-server-configuration/deploying-a-.war-file) and [spring](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-traditional-deployment.html#howto-create-a-deployable-war-file) documentation.

After conversion, the application will start normally, but it seems that some database (JPA) interactions have been broken (errors on search and DB updates).

I have a few related questions:

1. Is there additional configuration or considerations required to initialize/access JPA (via Hibernate) resources when converting from jar to war above what is specified in the spring documentation above?
2. What is the difference between running via maven goal `mvn
   spring-boot:run` (succeeds) vs running `java -jar <war-file>`
   (fails)?
3. Specifically related to the error I am seeing (copied below) regarding JPA criteria path, I found this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13369951/how-do-i-resolve-unable-to-resolve-attribute-organizationtype-id-against-path) suggesting that it might be an implementation problem. But back to question #2, if that is the case, why would it matter which way I ran the application if it's a code issue?

Potentially pertinent information:

- I have verified that the DB is responding via other clients.

Error message:

```
2018-11-08 17:46:22.578  INFO 17053 --- [nio-8443-exec-7] o.h.cache.internal.StandardQueryCache    : HHH000248: Starting query cache at region: query.Order

2018-11-08 17:46:22.820 ERROR 17053 --- [nio-8443-exec-7] .BroadleafSimpleMappingExceptionResolver : Error caught and handled.:05d420e6-69fc-4098-b085-2f8393a9ad7f

org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: Unable to resolve attribute [archiveStatus] against path; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unable to resolve attribute [archiveStatus] against path
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryUtils.convertJpaAccessExceptionIfPossible(EntityManagerFactoryUtils.java:384) ~[spring-orm-4.3.18.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.18.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.translateExceptionIfPossible(HibernateJpaDialect.java:246) ~[spring-orm-4.3.18.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.18.RELEASE]
    ...
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unable to resolve attribute [archiveStatus] against path
    at org.hibernate.ejb.criteria.path.AbstractPathImpl.unknownAttribute(AbstractPathImpl.java:120) ~[hibernate-entitymanager-4.1.11.Final.jar!/:4.1.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.ejb.criteria.path.AbstractPathImpl.locateAttribute(AbstractPathImpl.java:229) ~[hibernate-entitymanager-4.1.11.Final.jar!/:4.1.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.ejb.criteria.path.AbstractPathImpl.get(AbstractPathImpl.java:200) ~[hibernate-entitymanager-4.1.11.Final.jar!/:4.1.11.Final]
    at org.broadleafcommerce.core.search.dao.SearchFacetDaoImpl.readAllSearchFacets(SearchFacetDaoImpl.java:65) ~[broadleaf-framework-5.2.6-GA.jar!/:na]
    at org.broadleafcommerce.core.search.dao.SearchFacetDaoImpl$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$7573d5b3.invoke(<generated>) ~[broadleaf-framework-5.2.6-GA.jar!/:na]
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:204) ~[spring-core-4.3.18.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.18.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:736) ~[spring-aop-4.3.18.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.18.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157) ~[spring-aop-4.3.18.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.18.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:136) ~[spring-tx-4.3.18.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.18.RELEASE]
    ... 150 common frames omitted
```

Spring Boot Application configuration file:

```
  @SpringBootApplication
  @EnableAutoConfiguration
  public class SiteApplication extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

    @Configuration
    @EnableBroadleafSiteAutoConfiguration
    public static class BroadleafFrameworkConfiguration {}

      @Override
      protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
        return application.sources(SiteApplication.class);
      }

      public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(SiteApplication.class, args);
      }
  }
```

pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <parent>
    <groupId>org.broadleafcommerce</groupId>
    <artifactId>broadleaf-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>5.2.6-GA</version>
  </parent>

  <artifactId>our-site</artifactId>
  <packaging>war</packaging>
  ... 
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
      <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    ...
  </dependencies>
  ...
</project>
```

Archive Status class (per the error message)

```
@Embeddable
public class ArchiveStatus implements Serializable, SandBoxNonProductionSkip {

    @Column(name = "ARCHIVED")
    @AdminPresentation(friendlyName = "archived", visibility = VisibilityEnum.HIDDEN_ALL, group = "ArchiveStatus")
    protected Character archived = 'N';

    public Character getArchived() {
        return archived;
    }

    public void setArchived(Character archived) {
        this.archived = archived;
    }
}
```

Product Class (embeds Archive Status)

```
@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.JOINED)
@javax.persistence.Table(name = "BLC_PRODUCT")
//multi-column indexes don't appear to get exported correctly when declared at the field level, so declaring here as a workaround
@org.hibernate.annotations.Table(appliesTo = "BLC_PRODUCT", indexes = {
        @Index(name = "PRODUCT_URL_INDEX",
                columnNames = {"URL", "URL_KEY"}
        )
})
@Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.READ_WRITE, region = "blProducts")
... (BLC-specific overrides ommitted) ...
public class ProductImpl implements Product, ProductAdminPresentation, Status, AdminMainEntity, Locatable, TemplatePathContainer {
    ...
    @Embedded
    protected ArchiveStatus archiveStatus = new ArchiveStatus();
    ...
}
```

DAO method:

```
    public List<SearchFacet> readAllSearchFacets(FieldEntity entityType) {
        CriteriaBuilder builder = em.getCriteriaBuilder();
        CriteriaQuery<SearchFacet> criteria = builder.createQuery(SearchFacet.class);

        Root<SearchFacetImpl> facet = criteria.from(SearchFacetImpl.class);

        criteria.select(facet);

        Path<Character> archived = facet.get("archiveStatus").get("archived");

        criteria.where(
                builder.equal(facet.get("showOnSearch").as(Boolean.class), true),
                builder.or(builder.isNull(archived.as(String.class)),
                           builder.notEqual(archived.as(Character.class), 'Y')),
                facet.join("fieldType")
                        .join("indexField")
                        .join("field")
                        .get("entityType")
                        .as(String.class)
                        .in(entityType.getAllLookupTypes())
        );

        TypedQuery<SearchFacet> query = em.createQuery(criteria);
        query.setHint(QueryHints.HINT_CACHEABLE, true);
        query.setHint(QueryHints.HINT_CACHE_REGION, "query.Search");

        return query.getResultList();
    }
```

Comment: **Much** better.

Comment: To which runtime (e.g. Tomcat, Weblogic, JBoss, Websphere) you are deploying your `war` file to? Also, could you please do a `mvn dependency:tree` on your project and make a list of all the dependencies - of course you would understand what those dependencies do. Next go to your app server/servlet container's configuration and figure out if it is pre-pending any class loaders that load different versions/implementations of your intended dependencies. Let us know. If everything is same and your runtime is not polluting your application's classpath, then we ought to investigate further.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found the same error when I run DemoSite through compiled jarfile.

Take a look at this thread: https://github.com/BroadleafCommerce/DemoSite/issues/51

In my case, I had to include `spring-instrument` dependency in the site's pom.xml and specify its jar location with  `-javaagent` argument:

```sh
$ java -Xmx1024m -javaagent:./path/to/spring-instrument.jar -jar site.jar
```

Comment: This was a while ago, but I do believe you are right. I discovered the javaagent issue and moved on, I forgot to come back and update this. Thanks for closing the loop!

Comment: @Marquee... are you still working with Broadleaf? Did you have success?

Comment: Yes we are. We ended up using their enterprise solution after a few trials with the Community version as PoC. We went into production a few months ago. It has been a massive improvement over our previous e-commerce providers.

Comment: @Marquee can we share some ideas? How can I contact you?